# add initialValue to SequenceGenerator in jhipster V5.8.2

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, jhipster

I want to initialize the Sequence Generator to 4000 on my identifier but maven spits telling me that the initial value is already existing.

I would like to know how we define the initial value of an identifier on Jhipster V5.8.2 ?

My id :

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", initialValue=4000)
    private Long id;
```

and maven return that error: 
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Multiple references to database sequence [hibernate_sequence] were encountered attempting to set conflicting values for 'initial value'.  Found [1] and [4000]

Comment: might be an entity table using same sequence

Comment: the initialValue is set in the changelog of the liquibase config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using PostgreSQL, the initial value is set, if I remember correctly, in the `00000000000000_initial_schema.xml` file. Change the initial value and it should work.